# Purpose of the selector in ip xfrm state add

Tags: linux, vpn, ipsec

What does the selector (parameter sel) in the "ip xfrm state add" command achieve?

The source and destination addresses (and additional parameters like ports and protocol) are set in the ID section, but the selector contains a supplementary set of these. Example:

```
   ip xfrm state add src 10.0.0.1 dst 10.0.0.2 proto esp spi 123456 sel src 10.0.0.3 dst 10.0.0.4 enc blowfish  0xaabbccddee
```

This leads to the following result:

```
    src 10.0.0.1 dst 10.0.0.2
proto esp spi 0x0001e240 reqid 0 mode transport
replay-window 0 
enc cbc(blowfish) 0xaabbccddee
sel src 10.0.0.3/32 dst 10.0.0.4/32
```

Setkey seemingly does not have the opportunity to add such a selector value. It also does not show selectors in the output. The xfrm command from above produces the following "setkey -D" output:

```
   10.0.0.1 10.0.0.2 
esp mode=transport spi=123456(0x0001e240) reqid=0(0x00000000)
E: blowfish-cbc  aabbccdd ee
seq=0x00000000 replay=0 flags=0x00000000 state=mature 
created: Nov 26 01:25:39 2013   current: Nov 26 01:26:07 2013
diff: 28(s) hard: 0(s)  soft: 0(s)
last:                       hard: 0(s)  soft: 0(s)
current: 0(bytes)   hard: 0(bytes)  soft: 0(bytes)
allocated: 0    hard: 0 soft: 0
sadb_seq=0 pid=6959 refcnt=0
```

So what does the IPsec subsystem eventually do with this selector?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is ***probably*** straight from the IPsec standard ([RFC 4301: Security Architecture for the Internet Protocol](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4301)).
***Probably*** is because the standard describes *"nominal model"* i.e. implementations do not have to be exactly as described.

In [Section 4.4.2. Security Association Database (SAD)](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4301#section-4.4.2):

> For each of the selectors defined in Section 4.4.1.1, the entry for an inbound SA in the SAD MUST be initially populated with the value or values negotiated at the time the SA was created. ... For a receiver, these values are used to check that the header fields of an inbound packet (after IPsec processing) match the elector values negotiated for the SA.  Thus, the SAD acts as a cache for checking the selectors of inbound traffic arriving on SAs. For the receiver, this is part of verifying that a packet arriving on an SA is consistent with the policy for the SA.

In [Section 5.2. Processing Inbound IP Traffic (unprotected-to-protected)](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4301#section-5.2):

> IPsec MUST perform the following steps:
> ...
> 3a. If the packet is addressed to the IPsec device and AH or ESP is specified as the protocol, the packet is looked up in the SAD. ... If the packet is found in the SAD, process it accordingly (see step 4).
> 4.  Apply AH or ESP processing as specified, using the SAD entry selected in step 3a above.  Then match the packet against the inbound selectors identified by the SAD entry to verify that the received packet is appropriate for the SA via which it was received.
> 5.  If an IPsec system receives an inbound packet on an SA and the packet's header fields are not consistent with the selectors for the SA, it MUST discard the packet.

In short for your example

```bsh
ip xfrm state add src 10.0.0.1 dst 10.0.0.2 proto esp spi 123456 sel src 10.0.0.3 dst 10.0.0.4 enc blowfish  0xaabbccddee
```

when IPsec (ESP in this case) packet arrives at the server, then ***probably*** the following happens:

1. the part `src 10.0.0.1 dst 10.0.0.2 proto esp spi 123456` is used to find the corresponding SA.
   The SA is used to decrypt the packet's payload.
   Payload in transport mode IPsec is another IP packet.
2. the part `sel src 10.0.0.3 dst 10.0.0.4` is the selector from the SP which was used to create our SA.
   This selector is applied to the inner IP packet to verify that it is consistent with the SP.

Answer (score 0):

Selector is used in **tunnel** mode. i.e. networks that are (inter)connected by tunnel.

Comment: One could think so, but that's not the case. The Tunneled IP is visible only in the SPD not the SAD. `Ip xfrm policy` says
`src 10.0.0.1/32 dst 10.0.0.2/32 
dir out priority 0 ptype main 
tmpl src 192.168.0.1 dst 192.168.0.2
proto esp reqid 0 mode tunnel`
where 192. is the tunneling and 10.is the tunneled address. The SA (via `ip xfrm state`) then says
`src 192.168.0.1 dst 192.168.0.2
proto esp spi 0x000010e2 reqid 0 mode tunnel
replay-window 0 
enc cbc(blowfish) 0xaabbccddee
sel src 0.0.0.0/0 dst 0.0.0.0/0`.
So the selectors are still zero, even in tunnel mode.